# If user not select , disable the Button

Tags: angular

I'm stuck how to disable button once no emojis is selected.
this my html code , I  have emojis to select ( I get value from selected emojis).

I failed to do it, I get value from selected emoji with function.

```
<ng-template #mymodal let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Pain frequency</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">

    <div class="row emozies">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="data" [ngClass]="{'selected': selected == 1}">
          <div class="background-color1">
          </div>
          <div class="number-text">
            <p>
             <b>1 </b> 
            </p>
          </div>
          <img  src="../../assets/emozies/em1.PNG" alt="anurag" (click)="getEmojiValue('1')">
          <p class="my-text">
          <b> MILD </b>  
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="data" [ngClass]="{'selected': selected == 2}">
          <div class="background-color2">

          </div>
          <div class="number-text">
            <p>
             <b>2</b> 
            </p>
          </div>
          <img src="../../assets/emozies/em2.PNG" alt="anurag"  (click)="getEmojiValue('2')">
          <p class="my-text">
           <b> MODERATE </b>
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>
     
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button  (click)="onAppelMedical(data)"  type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark" >Ok</button>
 <!-- (click)="modal.close('Save click')" -->
  </div>

</ng-template>
```

[image]

any help please.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution :**

```
<button   [disabled]="!selected "  (click)="onAppelMedical(data)"  type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark" >Ok</button>
```